# C++ return a class instance with private constructor

Tags: c++, return

Hey I´ve got a Problem with a Class. It´s supposed to have a Method which returns the same class but with an other private constructor. But it fails with the specific error:

```
error C2248: 'std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits>::basic_ios' :
          cannot access private member declared in class '
```

This is the header file:

```
class XMLClass {
private:

    bool isGood();
    std::vector<std::string> xmlRowList;
    std::fstream xmlFS;
    XMLClass(std::string newList);

public:

    XMLClass(char *filename,std::string root);
    std::string getAttribute(char *att);
    std::string getText(void);
    XMLClass getChildNode(std::string childNode);
};
```

And this is the method which makes the error:

```
XMLClass XMLClass::getChildNode(std::string Node)
{
    XMLClass newXML(Node);
    return newXML;
}
```

Comment: how do you call the getChildNode in your code? could you please post it? Could you please post XMLClass(std::string newList) too?

Comment: This is probably caused by trying to copy `fstream`; but you've lost the vital part of the error message telling us which class has the inaccessible constructor.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is `fstream` class member - streams are non-copyable and as a consequence, so is your class.

To return an object from function by value, you need a copy constructor. But you don't have one because default generated one would be ill-formed.

If you've got C++11 support, you can implement move constructor for your class. If not, you'll need to store a pointer to the stream.

Answer (score 1):

Someone will probably write a more detailed answer, but I Think problem is This:

```
std::fstream xmlFS;
```

You can't copy it, which is needed for this return by value:

```
return newXML;
```

Solution should be to write copy constructor and assignment operator for your class, which handle this member variable correctly.

Check out [C++ Rule of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C++_programming%29)  while you are at it.

Comment: so should he store pointer to xmlFS instead and copy the pointer to new XMLClass instances?

Comment: Having pointer to object strewn across many copies of value object can be tricky... Using shared pointer, possible, but probably messy.